# AVPlayer stops playing when buffer is full and dosent resume

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avplayer, avplayerlayer, avplayeritem

I have a collection view with an `AVPlayer` inside the cell and the `AVPlayer` starts playing the `AVPlayerItem` in a loop when

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

gets called. this works well but the problem is that after the `AVPlayer` is playing the item a few times the video is no longer shown but i can hear its sound. 
I also add an observer for the value `@"playbackBufferFull"` for each item that is played like that:

```
[item addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferFull" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

i noticed that when the video stops the observer method of the value `@"playbackBufferFull"` gets called, first of all i would like to know what causes the buffer the get full, the second and most important is how can i resume the `AVPlayer` when the video stops;
i tried calling `[cell.videoPlayer play];` and to replace the item with a new one and it didnt work, the observer method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                                    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {


                if ([object isKindOfClass:[AVPlayerItem class]] && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackBufferFull"])
                {
                  //this method is get called when the video stop showing but i can still hear it
                 //how can i resume the video?
                }

            }
```

Comment: i had this problem also!
i can't find the better way for it  , but in dispatch_after (w8 for buffer ready again ) --> i call avplayer play method again and it cause resume :)

Comment: hi, can you please send me the full code of the dispatch_after? when is the buffer ready again?

Comment: @aviv_elk did you managed to play the video as you described? I am trying to play the video with AVPlayer and AVPlayerLayer in TableViewCell. I am also facing the issue of no playing a video after a while.

Answer (score 1):

my solution is :

first add observe for `AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification` in `viewDidLoad` or ...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification
                                           object:self.avPlayer.currentItem];

-(void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification*)noti

{
//thisisn't good way but i can't find the best way for detect best place for resume again.
NSLog(@"\n\n give Error while Streaminggggg");
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.avPlayer play];
 });
}
```

**BUT**
maybe you can find the best way to call play method again for resume!
please check do you get `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay` keypatch ?
if you get , you can call `play` method there.
please notify me about the result

Comment: this is the available way to detect and replay the AVPlayer, but the problem arises while playing it in cell in continuous loop to produce the GIF like feel with MP4 Video. have you tried something similar?